# Receiving an incorrect time in SQL

Tags: reactjs

I'm interested in getting a full date in SQL this way 2021/02/02 20:12:36
And the date is kept in such a way 2021/02/02 00:00:00
On the server side I get a correct date like this 2021/02/02 20:12:36
On the client side I get this way 2021/02/02 03:00:00
This is the format I get in React
I don't know why:(

Maybe here's the problem

```
const FormatDate = (date) => {
    try {
    console.log(date);
    return format(date, "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
    } catch (e) {
    return "";
    }
};
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If the *date kept* does not include a time-of-day, why output one in the first place? Why expect anything but "hours from zero meridian"? I consider 3 o'clock correct from Franz-Josef-Land over the Arabian Peninsula to Madagascar (or Finland to Madagascar if you "believe" in *daylight savings time*), and `2021/02/02 20:12:36` *weird*.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is error of browser auto add offset at client

You can try this code to show right time at client

```js
new Date(DATE_REPONSE_FROM_SERVER).getTime() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000
```

But you need add offset at server if you send this time to server

Other way, I this you convert time to string and response this string

Hope this help for you

Comment: An offset of 20:12:36? No, this it the time part being truncated somehow. Yes, there's also an offset problem, but it's not the entire problem

Comment: And then there's the problem with the solution. `new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000` makes absolutely no sense. In *many* places in the world, the offset from UTC changes depending on the time of year. For example, it's -5:00 in the winter here, and -4:00 in the summer.